# Zephyr: where is comments field visible?

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jira-zephyr

I'm stumped - In Jira or any Zephyr report, where does one see the value that was added to comments?  ie:

Here's my request, I've added "Comment":"test 999", and can see it in the response, but can't find it in any existing report?

```
URL: http://localhost:8080/jira/rest/zapi/latest/execution/" + executionId + "/execute
BODY: {"status":"1","comment":"test 999"}
```

Here's the response:

response:

```
{"id":5123,"orderId":4637,"executionStatus":"1","executedOn":"Today 1:59 PM","executedBy":"xxxxx","executedByDisplay":"xxxxx","comment":"test 999","htmlComment":"test 999","cycleId":806,"cycleName":"Test Cycle 4","versionId":12219,"versionName":"1.1","projectId":11114,"createdBy":"xxxxx","modifiedBy":"xxxxx","issueId":73897,"issueKey":"KEY-1","summary":"Test 7","issueDescription":"<p>Functional test case for 'Test 7'</p>","label":"","component":"","projectKey":"KEY"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out - Click on the test case, in section Test Executions, click on the "E" button on the right side.  That's where the comments are stored.